# Find string in possibly multiple parentheses?

Tags: python, regex

I am looking for a regular expression that discriminates between a string that contains a numerical value enclosed between parentheses, and a string that contains outside of them. The problem is, parentheses may be embedded into each other:

So, for example the expression should match the following strings:

- hey(example1)
- also(this(onetoo2(hard)))
- but(here(is(a(harder)one)maybe23)Hehe)

But it should not match any of the following:

- this(one)is22misleading
- how(to(go)on)with(multiple)3parent(heses(around))

So far I've tried

> \d[A-Za-z] \)

and easy things like this one. The problem with this one is it does not match the example 2, because it has a ( string after it.

How could I solve this one?

Comment: Seems to me, you are looking for a lexer and parser. eeg flex and bison.

Comment: In string `how(to(go)on)with(multiple)3parent(heses(around))` digit is already enclosed by outer `()`. Do you got any rule to differentiate it from `but(here(is(a(harder)one)maybe23)Hehe)` ? Because both seems similar.

Comment: The question between that two is that the first one contains a ( after the digit, still in the original parentheses. If it hadnt been allowed, my example woould have been enough. But it is allowed.

Comment: So you mean there should be no group `()` after a number has appeared ?

Comment: Should be hard to do with regexes, since even detecting correct parentheses nesting is going beyond the realm of FSA's and regular languages. It's context-free...

Comment: No, I mean there could be anything after it. The ony thing that matters whether is it enclosed in any kind of pairs of parentheses

Comment: Nested parentheses are the canonical example of things that are hard to do with regular expressions; consider a different approach.

Comment: It might be easier to just count the number of open and close parentheses before the digit. As it has been mentioned in comments above, regex are not the best way to go here.

Comment: In a computer science, searching for expressions that me be recursively embedded (as your problem above) is done with what is called a "context free grammar" (this is implemented by a parser--see other comments).  Regular expressions are known to be unable to implement "context-free grammars" (**unless you limit the depth of embedded parentheses**, but the resulting regex can get quite complicated).  You can look for these words.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not one of pattern matching. That means regular expressions are not the right tool for this.

Instead, you need lexical analysis and parsing. There are [many libraries available for that job](https://wiki.python.org/moin/LanguageParsing).

You might try the [`parsing`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/parsing) or [`pyparsing`](https://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) libraries.

Answer (score 0):

These type of regexes are not always easy, but sometimes it's possible to come up with a way provided the input remains somewhat consistent. A  pattern generally like this should work:

```
(.*(\([\d]+[^(].*\)|\(.*[^)][\d]+.*\)).*)
```

**Code**:

```
import re

p = re.compile(ur'(.*(\([\d]+[^(].*\)|\(.*[^)][\d]+.*\)).*)', re.MULTILINE)

result = re.findall(p, searchtext)
print(result)
```

**Result**:

https://regex101.com/r/aL8bB8/1

Comment: I think this will fail on `hello(1(world))` which should be a match from the OPs description.

Comment: Yes, likely, but the pattern can be adapted for it. Hopefully they can learn from this a bit ... that's the goal. Thanks.